# Is tracking individual user behavior possible in Google Analytics Premium for Android app?

Tags: android, google-analytics, user-tracking

Is Tracking of user Behavior like which activity user saw, what time he saw them , and all possible.  Or Can this only be done from the back end ?
Does Google Analytic Premium has this feature ?

**Edit:**

We are looking to track the user behavior on android application and want to know the details of the pages the user has visited within the app.

The Google Analytics gives me the count of the visits however it does not confirm as to who visited which page. The user_id tracking for Google Analytics is not working for some reasons.

Is there a tool where we can record the user behavior to eventually improve the app functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track individual users, you need to send a unique userId to google analytics as a custom dimension value. Make sure the Id you send to google is not PII as that is against google's privacy policy. You don't need to have a premium account to implement this behavior.

If you are not aware of how custom dimensions work, please check this link for more info on it

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

Also for things like at what time a particular user viewed a page, you can look at generating Custom Reports. Select Parameter Time from Dimensions Tab in Custom Reports. More info here.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en